# How can I adjust week numbering in Angular Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, week-number

By default the week numbering system for the Angular Bootstrap Datepicker is different than the one I need to be displayed. For example, `May 7, 2021` is in `WW18` by default but I need it to show as `WW19`. I can't find a way to adjust or override the week numbers in the docs.

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [showWeekNumbers]="true" [firstDayOfWeek]="7">
<button (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
</button>
```

[screen shot of calendar with week numbers highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt1R6.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the demo on how to do it](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#i18n).

That's how the datepicker shows the week number:

```html
<div *ngIf="showWeekNumbers" class="ngb-dp-week-number small text-muted">{{ i18n.getWeekNumerals(week.number) }}</div>
```

```js
export class NgbDatepickerMonthView {

  constructor(public i18n: NgbDatepickerI18n) {}

}
```

So you can provide the implementation of the `NgbDatepickerI18n` with `getWeekNumerals` method following the custom logic you need.

Comment: Ugh, I was wrong about the nature of my problem. @IAfanasov, your answer is correct and solves my stated problem. However, upon furture investigation, I determined that the week numbers aren't just off by one - it has to do with how week numbers are converted from the ISO standard to the system used by the tool users. Is there a way to get the full date, or at least the year, from within the getWeekNumerals method?

Comment: this method has just one argument - week number. Unfortunately no way to get the full date there